# could not able to understand how comma operator works

Tags: c++

In this below program I have overloaded commaoperator. But, why `comma operator` is not taking considering the `first element/object`.

```
class Point {
  int x, y;
public:
  Point() {}
  Point(int px, int py) 
  {x = px;y = py;}
  void show() {
    cout << x << " ";
    cout << y << "\n";
  }
  Point operator+(Point op2);
  Point operator,(Point op2);
};

// overload comma for Point
Point Point::operator,(Point op2)
{
  Point temp;
  temp.x = op2.x;
  temp.y = op2.y;
  cout << op2.x << " " << op2.y << "\n";
  return temp;
}

// Overload + for Point
Point Point::operator+(Point op2)
{
  Point temp;
  temp.x = op2.x + x;
  temp.y = op2.y + y;
  return temp;
}

int main()
{
  Point ob1(10, 20), ob2( 5, 30), ob3(1, 1);
  Point ob4;
  ob1 = (ob1, ob2+ob2, ob3);//Why control is not reaching comma operator for ob1?
  ob1 = (ob3, ob2+ob2, ob1);//Why control is not reaching comma operator for ob3?
  ob4 = (ob3+ob2, ob1+ob3);//Why control is not reaching comma operator for ob3+ob2?
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried to understand `,` operator also but could not able to find the solution.

```
  ob1 = (ob1, ob2+ob2, ob3);//Why control is not reaching comma operator for ob1?
  ob1 = (ob3, ob2+ob2, ob1);//Why control is not reaching comma operator for ob3?
  ob4 = (ob3+ob2, ob1+ob3);//Why control is not reaching comma operator for ob3+ob2?
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I don't think a comma is an operator, it's part of the syntax rather.

Comment: Why on earth would you overload the comma operator for a point? What does that even mean? Your implementation is meaningless.

Comment: I understand you're doing this for learning purposes, but in practice, you should **never** overload the comma operator, because it loses its specific semantics (the guaranteed evaluation order). The same holds for `&&` and `||`.

Comment: @ThaMe90 That's simply not true. A comma is indeed an operator, and can be overridden.

Comment: @ThaMe90 comma is indeed an operator, even in `C`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: @Angew, mbratch: Oops, indeed you're correct. I was to fast.. :o

Comment: @SebastianRedl: I got this question in an interview. I got program in internet. So, I have tried to check the same. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0200__Operator-Overloading/overloadcommaforPoint.htm

Comment: @Angew: See my comment above

Comment: Why do you think it's not reaching it? [This live example](http://ideone.com/1vGHEC) shows 5 outputs - 1 for each comma operator.

Comment: Why do you say that the control is not reaching the comma operator? Are you not seeing the output from inside the *comma* operator? [Tests](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5bebf0438490627) show that the `operator,` **is** called.

Comment: This question is obfuscating things too much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does reach it. But since you're only printing out the values of the argument of `operator,` and never of `this`, you don't get to see it printed out.

Answer (score 5):

> Why control is not reaching comma operator for ob1?

I guess you're asking, why does this line only output two points: `10 60` for `ob2+ob2`, and `1 1` for `ob3`. This is because you only invoke the comma operator twice; each time, it outputs its right-hand argument and ignores its left-hand argument.

The line of code is equivalent to

```
ob1.operator,(ob2+ob2).operator,(ob3);
```

making it clear that it's only called twice. `ob1` is evaluated, but the operator doesn't do anything with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
ob1 = (ob1, ob2+ob2, ob3);//Why control is not reaching comma operator for ob1?
```

It does, you just didn't do anything to notice it.
You defined the operator as a member function. Now let's rewrite the expression above, ignoring the left side of assignment operator:

```
    (ob1.operator,(ob2+ob2)).operator,(ob3);
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 // displays contents of ob2+ob2
 //                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 //                   displays contents of ob3
```

Or equivalent, but easier to understand:

```
 {
     Point temp = ob1.operator,(ob2+ob2);
     temp.operator,(obj3);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never change the semantics of the operators you're overloading. The comma operator evaluates the left expression, executes any side effects, discards the result, then evaluates the second and returns the evaluated result (and type).